# There is only one distinct pair of numbers that multiply to a given number and sum to a given number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Statement:

There is only one distinct pair of numbers that multiply to a given number and sum to a given number.

Proof (almost complete):

$$x+y=c_1 {}{}{}{} (1)$$

$$xy=c_2 {}{}{}{} (2)$$

We have from (1) that $y=c_1-x$, hence:

$$x(c_1-x)=c_2$$

Solving for $x$ from the (1) we also have:

$$y(c_1-y)=c_2$$

These are the same equations and thus must have the same solution set $x=\{x_0,y_0\}$ and $y=\{x_0,y_0\}$. They are quadratics and thus have at most $2$ distinct solutions in $\mathbb{C}$, giving us two solutions to our system of equations $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(y_0,x_0)$, which can be treated as one set of solutions , if they have one we still have one set of solutions.

Above what is left to prove is why $(x_0,x_0)$ and $(y_0,y_0)$ can't be solutions in the case $x_0 \neq y_0$, and why the pairs $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(y_0,x_0)$ work (the later follows from the definition of $x_0$ and $y_0$. How can I do this?

Also, how can I prove this without the symmetry of the equations?

The reason I'm interested is that I'm trying to explain to myself why a factoring method works:

$$(dx+e)(fx+g)=dfx^2+efx+gdx+eg=ax^2+bx+c$$

Notice $(df)(eg)=(ef)(gd)=(a)(c)$ and $ef+gd=b$. If we rearrange  $efx$ and $gdx$ around (switching spots) we still have a quadratic favorable by grouping. Now all that is left to figure out that this method of factoring quadratic works is to show that $ef$ and $gd$ are the only two elements that add to $df+gf=b$ and multiply to $efgd$, that is equivalent to the following question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with
$$ 
x + y = c_1 \\
x \, y = c_2
$$
and transform to
$$
y = c_1 - x \\
x (c_1 - x) = c_2
$$
where the second equation can be transformed to
$$
0 = x^2 - c_1 x + c_2 = 
(x - c_1/2)^2 + c_2 - c_1^2/4 \iff \\
x = \frac{c_1 \pm \sqrt{c_1^2 - 4 c_2}}{2}
$$
so depending on $\Delta = c_1^2 - 4 c_2$ we have zero, one or two solutions $(x, y)$.

Comment: But don't we have $4$ possible solutions $(x_0,x_0),(y_0,y_0),(x_0,y_0),(y_0,x_0)$?

Comment: Hmm. The first equation is a line with normal vector $(1,1)$ and the distance to the origin $c_1/\sqrt{2}$, the second a hyperbola ($c_2 \ne 0$) or the coordinate cross ($c_2 = 0$). So we have zero, one or twp solutions in the first case, and one or two in the second case.

Comment: Yes never mind I see that $x=\frac{c_1 + \sqrt{c_1^2 - 4 c_2}}{2}$ corresponds to one value of $y=\frac{c}{x}$ and $x = \frac{c_1 - \sqrt{c_1^2 - 4 c_2}}{2}$ corresponds to another. $x,\frac{c}{x}$ must be a solution pair because it followed from our equations. On the other hand if $x \neq y$, then $(x,x)$ or $(y,y)$ can't be a solution pair in the case $x\neq \frac{c}{x} =y$ or $y \neq \frac{c}{y}=x$ because then $(x)(x) \neq c$, and thus (2) will not be satisfied. Right @mvw ?

Comment: The reason I ask my previous comment is because you show there are two solutions and from my work they have to be one of the two $(x,y),(y,x),(x,x),(y,y)$  but why can't they be $(x,x),(y,y)$ if $x \neq y$ is another question which I attempted to answer in my previous comment. Ps $x$ and $y$ are the two solutions (or 1 solution if $x=y$) to the quadratic  $x(c_1-x)=c_2$. I know notation is a bit sloppy I should've used $x_0$ or something.

Answer (score 1):

If two numbers add to $a$ then you can write them as $\frac{a-x}{2}$ and $\frac{a+x}{2}$. The product is therefore $\frac{a^2-x^2}{4}$, clearly $x^2=y^2\iff x=\pm y$, but this only corresponds to swapping the two numbers.